# Perl Form Validation using CGI scripting

Tags: perl, validation

I'm trying to achieve one last task for my assignment is to validate the form before submit it to the another CGI program.

What happen is that I have a simple CGI program that will ask user to input the data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI qw/:standard/;

# Standard HTTP header
print header();

# Write information to data file and produce a form
&printForm();

# Finish HTML page
print end_html();

# This sub will create a form to access the print_fortune.cgi script
sub printForm
{
        print qq~

<html>
<head><title>My Search Engine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="b1.cgi" method="GET">
        What is your e-msil address? <input type="text" name="passing" size=40>
        <input type="submit" value="send address">
        <input type="hidden" name="form" value="insert" />
        </form>

<form method="get" action="b1.cgi" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<input type="text" name="search" value="" size="30" /><br />

<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="name" checked="checked" />name</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="author" />author</label><label>

<input type="radio" name="option" value="url" />url</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="keyword" />keyword</label>

<input type="submit" name=".submit" value="Search" />
<input type="hidden" name="passing" value="http://default.com" />

<div><input type="hidden" name="form" value="search"  /></div></form>


</body>
```

So the above program contains two forms. One is to add new data to the database and the other one is to search from the database.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use LWP::Simple;
use CGI;
use HTML::HeadParser;
use DBI;

my $serverName = "";
my $serverPort = "";

my $serverUser = "";
my $serverPass = "";
my $serverDb   = "";

my $serverTabl = "";

$cgi = CGI->new;

my $pass = $cgi->param('passing');

$URL = get ("$pass");

$head = HTML::HeadParser->new;

$head->parse("$URL");

my $methods = $cgi->param('form');


if ($methods eq "insert"){

insert_entry();

}

show_entries();

sub insert_entry {
    my ($dbh, $success, $name, $author, $url,$temp);

    $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$serverDb;host=$serverName;port=$serverPort",$serverUser,$serverPass);
    $name = $head->header('X-Meta-Name');
    $author = $head->header('X-Meta-Author');
    $url = $cgi->param('passing');
    $temp = $head->header('X-Meta-Keywords');
    @keyword = split(/,/,$temp);


    $success = $dbh->do("INSERT INTO $serverTabl(name,author,url,keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", undef,$name,$
author,$url,$keyword[0],$keyword[1],$keyword[2],$keyword[3],$keyword[4]);
    $dbh->disconnect;
    if($success != 1) {
       return "Sorry, the database was unable to add your entry.
                                Please try again later.";
    } else {
        return;
      }
}

sub show_entries {
    my ($dbh, $sth, @row);
    my $search = $cgi->param('search');
    my $option = $cgi->param('option');

    $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$serverDb;host=$serverName;port=$serverPort",$serverUser,$serverPass);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *
                          FROM $serverTabl
                          WHERE $option LIKE '%$search%'");
    $sth->execute;
    print "Existing Entries",HR;
    while(@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
          $row[5] = scalar(localtime($row[5]));
          print "<table border='2'><tr>";
          print "<td>" .  $row[0] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Name" . $row[1] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Author" . $row[2] . "</td>";
          print "<td>URL" . $row[3] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Keyword1" . $row[4] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Keyword2" . $row[5] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Keyword3" . $row[6] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Keyword4" . $row[7] . "</td>";
          print "<td>Keyword5" . $row[8] . "</td>";
          print "</tr></table>";
     }
     $sth->finish;
     $dbh->disconnect;
}
```

So now the question is how can I do a regular expression for the form submission before it goes to the second program?

I want to do validation for

- `name`  allows spaces but only alphabetical characters
- `author` allows spaces but only alphabetical characters
- `keywords` allows no spaces and only alphabetical characters
- `url` only allows alphanumerical characters and the following  :/.~?=+&    No two periods can exist consecutively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) Perl document lists all the `\p` regular expression properties.

For a string that contains only letters, you want

```
/^[\p{Alpha}]+$/
```

For a string that contains only letters and spaces you want

```
/^[\p{Alpha}\x20]+$/
```

To match a URL the documentation of the [`URI` module](https://metacpan.org/module/URI#PARSING-URIs-WITH-REGEXP) gives this as an *official* pattern to match a URL

```
m|^(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$|
```

Be sure to cite the references in your work to get extra marks!